# Run python script with args in javascript with exec

Tags: javascript, child-process

I have inputs such as latitude, longitude and frequency.
I would like to run this command on a JS file :

```
exec(`python test.py '{"latitude":${latitude},"longitude":${longitude},"frequency":${frequency}}'`, (error, stdout, stderr) => { .... })
```

But when I run I have the following error :

```
error: Command failed: python test.py '{"latitude":48.118097,"longitude":-1.636503,"frequency":2.4}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    data=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And my python script begin with

```
import sys
import json
data=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Moreover if I just run my python script without args, and write random data directly in the python script, it works. So I think it's a problem of the args written in the exec command.

Can you please help me.

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: When I run the python script with my JS file I can't see the print of my python script.

Comment: You should print `stdout` in the callback function.

Comment: I think this is because `sys.argv[1]` is already a string, so that string will now also contain the leading and trailing apostrophe. Try changing your `test.py` script to use `data=json.loads(sys.argv[1].replace("'", ""))` instead.

Comment: Matt I tried your advice but it doesn't work.

Comment: Another option might be to try importing the `ast` module and using `data = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add double quotes?

```
python test.py '\"{"latitude":48.118097,"longitude":-1.636503,"frequency":2.4}\"'
```